# Displaying Record Once in SSRS Table

Tags: ssrs-2008, ssrs-expression

I've created a table from a procedure that will display a summary of all incentives from a given collection operation or recruiter in my report. But if the collection operation or recruiter has multiple incentives assigned to their drives during the time period, it will repeat the same collection operation or recruiter on each line.  If possible, I'd like to only display the first time it occurs and then leave a blank space until it hits a new collection operation/recruiter.

See screenshot for example:
[image]

Is there a way to create an expression to handle this? Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is Groupings. If you add a row grouping on your "Collection Operation" column it should do a trick. To add a group Right click on your details row. just like you would to add a row. There should be an option to add a parent group. Select that and tell it you want to group on "Collection Operation" and click "Ok". You may have to adjust your formatting a little, but I think this will achieve what you are going for.

I just noticed the recruiter Column. To make that only display once you will need to use an expression. Now that you have a loop you should be able to write an expression that determines your position within the group and blank it out when it isn't the first row.

Comment: Thanks Brandon, I'll give that a shot tomorrow.  And for the Recruiter, that is actually a separate table running a separate procedure so the same Grouping should be able to be applied to it.

Comment: Ok I didn't realize that. Then, yes the same grouping should work for that as well.

Comment: Thanks, was off for a few days but just tried this out and it works great.  Thanks again.